# Call java-script function, hit button and download file using powershell

Tags: powershell, java, javascript

I am having below code which navigates to page but not invoking JavaScript function. What I want is:
1. Open web page
2. Call javascript function
3. Hit "OK" button
4. And download csv file which has link.

I'm new to powershell script, any help will be appreciated. 
With below code, I am getting error:

```
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate('https://webtac.industrysoftware.automation.siemens.com/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=frames&g_userid=a3rgcw&g_session_id=7302840')
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 500} 
$link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.href -eq "javascript:parent.gotoSearch('advanced');"}
$link.click()
```

Error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\workdir\test - Copy.ps1:8 char:12
+ $link.click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Javasript code:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.gotoSearch('advanced')">Advanced Search</a>
```

Html button code:

```
<input type="button" name="ok" id="ok" value=" OK " onclick="onSubmitFunction()">
```

Csv file save code:

```
<a href="javascript:getResultDataFile('csv')">[Comma-Delimited Text (CSV)]</a>
```

Comment: The webpage you mention in your script requires a login, did you try to automate this as well in the script ? Maybe that's why it do not find the right bouton to click ?

Comment: Actually, when I open page be it manually or thru excel vba, it opens logged in page, doesn't ask for log in.

Comment: Ok, and when your script opens the page in IE, does it open already logged in ?

Comment: Yes, above PS script opens page with already logged in.

Comment: If you run the code manually, in ISE for instance, are you able to expand the $link variable ? Does it contain the desired button's information ? If not, what's the error ?

Comment: I don't know what ISE means, please tell me how to run code in it.

Comment: Powershell ISE is an Integrated Scripting Environment in which you can, among other things, run your script line per line for troubleshooting purposes. I'm sure Internet is full of tutorials for you to learn how to use it.

Comment: What I am selecting is one of the option in dropdwon named "Advanced Search". When run code in ISE, it gives same error at '$link.click()'

Comment: What if you run each line separately ? And then run only $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.href -eq "javascript:parent.gotoSearch('advanced');"} => does is returns something ? Maybe that part is not good and does not return anything, and that's why it can't click ?

Comment: Getting error at line that you specified: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:34
+ $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName <<<< ('A') | Where-Object {$_.href -eq "javascript:parent.gotoSearch('advanced');"}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementsByTagName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull